# Simple Calculation on Local Rings.

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

Let $p$ be prime and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the local ring. I already know, that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align}

1. What ist the explicit map?
2. There exists some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p|t$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/t\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/t\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for #1: Obviously $a$ maps to $a+p\Bbb Z$ for $a\in\Bbb Z$. Suppose $a/b$ maps to $c+p\Bbb Z$. Then what can you say about $bc$ mod $p$? What does this tell you about $c$? (This is why it's important $p\nmid b$.)

Hint for #2: Prove $q\,\Bbb Z_{(p)}=\Bbb Z_{(p)}=q^{-1}\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ for any prime $q\ne p$. Then argue $t\Bbb Z_{(p)}=p^{v_p(t)}\Bbb Z_{(p)}$.

Comment: @annon What is $v_p(t)$? Is this just $t=np$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @R2D2 Please do not accept answers you do not understand. The notation $v_p(t)$ (for $p$-adic valuation) means the highest exponent of $p$ appearing in $t$'s prime factorization (which applies to rationals just as it applies to integers). For example $v_2(4/3)=2$.

Comment: 2. does not hold for all $t \in R$, such that $p|t$. Take $p=3$ and $t=6$.

Comment: @R2D2 Correct. ${}$

Comment: @annon Honestly I have difficulties to calculate in $\mathbb{Z_{(p)}}/t\mathbb{Z_{(p)}}$. So for which $t \in R$ does it hold? Only for $t=p^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @R2D2 First of all you need $t\in\Bbb Z$ for $t\Bbb Z$ to make sense. Second of all, did you read my hint? Do you understand how to apply my hint? (Use prime factorization.)

Comment: @annon Yes I read your hint and understood it - but no, I am not sure about the application. I mean since $t\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=p^{\upsilon_p(t)}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, I know, that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/t\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p^{\upsilon_p(t)}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. But is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p^{\upsilon_p(t)}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z}/p^{\upsilon_p(t)}\mathbb{Z}$. If yes I know, that $t$ must equal $p^n$ to hold my required isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Z_{(p)}/p^v\Bbb Z_{(p)}\cong\Bbb Z/p^v\Bbb Z$.